# Starting Websphere Application Server in local system

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I have been assigned a work to migrate an application from weblogic to websphere. Never worked with websphere.

My company installed WAS in my local. Trying to start gave error - "no profiles exist". There was no profiles directory so I created one. Used manageprofile.bat and created a profile and under the bin folder of myprofile, tried running serverStart.bat but it didn't work.

How to start server in websphere? What is federated node and template path? Any easy guide for beginners as whatever I find is hard and does not suit my case. Version 8.0.0.
Also what is the alternative here to Weblogic's Admin Server and Managed Server?
Also where is dmgr server I cant locate it.

Comment: Request not to close as the info provided in the Answer is good for beginners.

Comment: I'd just like to add that the info page for the 'websphere' tag has several excellent resources for learning WebSphere. Located [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/websphere/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Websphere!  It can be a little intimidating at first but hang in there.

Not quite sure what you created the first time but invoke 
bin\ProfileManagement\pmt.bat to bring up the GUI version.

Create an application server, pick "typical" and follow the prompts  You might not want administrative security if you're just getting started, it can be added later. then click "create", then "finish".  After that you'll have a window open that shows what the available profiles are.

The default name of the server is server1.

go there (was_home\profiles(profile_name)\bin and run startserver(.bat/.sh) server1.

Your next question is probably "where in the heck is the administrative console".  look at (profile_name)/logs/AboutThisProfile.txt to find the port.

You'll see something like:
Administrative console port: 9064

Access localhost:(whatever port)/ibm/console with a browser and you're in.

Any apps you install will be reachable on one of these found in AboutThisProfile: 
HTTP transport port: (some port) or
HTTPS transport port: (some port)

You can run pmt again to delete profiles / make more, or go down the advanced path and pick the ports, etc.

(this is just the simplest, stand alone appserver).

I've never touched weblogic but I'll bet the websphere equivalent of the 
admin server is websphere's deployment manager, or dmgr profile.  If you installed WebSphere ND, then from that pmt tool you can create what's called a  "cell" profile, which will set up the deployment manager, a thing called a "nodeagent" (think "middleman"), and an appserver.  I try to just use a standalone appserver profile instead when I can because it keeps things simpler.

Here are a few points on ND and how it's organized:

A "node" is a group of server(s).  The pattern of one node per computer is common but there can be more than one on a computer if the computer has sufficient resources.  The deployment manager (dmgr) is in it's own node.  When nodes and servers are under control of the dmgr they are said to be "federated", that is, the dmgr provides the administrative console and controls all of them.

Each server node has a "node agent" jvm which does most of the work of the dmgr for that node.  Startnode starts that jvm.  Federated appservers won't start unless the node agent is running.  Once dmgr and node agent(s) are running, the dmgr console can be used to start / stop / add / delete servers and applications on any node.

The add/removeNode.sh utilities federate or unfederate nodes.

The simplest way to get started with this "topology", as they call it, is to create a "cell" profile which has the dmgr, node agent, and a single server already federated.  You can add more nodes and servers later as you need them.

Comment: Thanks. Great startup answer. Not sure why when I used manageprofile.bat tool, the file AboutThisProfile.txt wasn't there but I was able to open the Admin Console by using default http port 9060. When I used the pmt.bat UI tool, AboutThisProfile.txt file was created with http port. One difference I noticed is the console opens for only this profile. I think I need to create a DMGR profile to view all profiles.

Comment: it would also be helpful if you can add what is Node/server federation. And what does startNode.bat do. Thanks